External Monitor flicker when used with Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS Thinkpad
I have the issue of external monitor flickering when used with my Thinkpad Ubuntu laptop.
The system info is here:
$uname -a
Linux yoga4 6.5.0-1027-oem #28-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Jul 25 13:32:46 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


Monitor is : Philips Consumer Electronics Company 25"
I have followed everything mentioned in this useful link:(Ubuntu external full HD monitor flicker)

Frequency, personal laptop has frequency 60,00 Hz, external monitor has 59,95 Hz (have no choice to change the monitor frequency).
Resolution, personal laptop has 1920x1080(16:9), external monitor has 2560x1440(16:9)
HDMi cable is fine, since it works fine with two other DELL laptop
No additional software update is pending.
Did not really played around much with Grub though.

I would really appreciate if someone has other ideas to fix this annoying issue.
Many Thanks,

This is a TV not a computer monitor?

On Display, that was exactly written for the monitor name 'Philips Consumer Electronics Company 25'.
